# JQuery: GetJson give me only undefined data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I'm trying to parse a JSON result with this script:

```
$.getJSON( url, function(data){
    var items=[];
    $.each(data,function(i,item){
        items.push("<div class='col-lg-12' >");
        items.push( " By "+ item.user_name +": "+ item.created_at);                
        items.push("</div>");
        items.push("<div class='col-lg-12' >");
        items.push( "<p>" + item.text + "</p>" );                
        items.push("</div>");
    });
    $( "<ul/>", {
        "class": "my-new-list",
        html: items.join( "" )
    }).appendTo( "#commentaires" );
});
```

The JSON to parse is

```
[
    [
        {
            "text": "text1",
            "created_at": "12 May, 2015",
            "user_name": "gilbert moignon"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "text": "text2",
            "created_at": "12 May, 2015",
            "user_name": "jean bono"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "text": "text3",
            "created_at": "12 May, 2015",
            "user_name": "gerard mentor"
        }
    ]
]
```

Unfortunaltely, for an unknow reason, I only see `undefined` instead of my data.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the `url`you try to retrieve, is it an online or local file ?

Comment: url is a local file. i tryed it with '$('#commentaires').load(url);' and received the json i gave on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your code as follow:

Because you are parsing nested arrays and have only one element in array you have to use `item[0]` inside `each`:

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    item = item[0];
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/dydect3t/